# c#: (True==True) returning False

Tags: c#, boolean

I'm having a problem with (true==true) returning false.

```
Console.WriteLine(
    useaction.Postcondition[goalneeds].ToString() + "==" + 
    current[goalneeds].ToString() + " returns " + 
    (useaction.Postcondition[goalneeds] == current[goalneeds]).ToString());
```

Output:`True==True returns False`

useaction.Postcondition is of the same type as current.

Despite what the preview color says, "Postcondition" is not static

Any help is appreciated, I don't know any other relevant information I can share.

Solution:

```
                bool a = (bool)useaction.Postcondition[goalneeds];
                bool b = (bool)current[goalneeds];
                Console.WriteLine(a.ToString() + "==" + b.ToString() + " returns " + (a==b).ToString());
```

The first code compared object types. The second code compared bools.

Comment: Are `useaction.Postcondition[goalneeds]` real `bool`s?

Comment: What is the type of both arrays?

Comment: And what type is `useaction.Postcondition`? And do you mutate one of the collections in another thread?

Comment: `true=="true"` is not the same as `true==true`

Comment: And where do those bools come from? Clean managed code? Or perhaps unmanaged code or unsafe managed?

Comment: What are the types of `useaction.PostCondition` and `current`?

Comment: Another possibility are boxed `bool`s those would compare using referential equality, instead of value equality.

Comment: Just because ToString() gives the same result for two values doesn't mean the values are the same. At the very least, we need to know the types involved.

Comment: CodeInChaos had the right idea. I was comparing objects, not bools. The fixed code is in the edit

Comment: To avoid this issue in the future, consider using `.Equals()` instead of `==`, which works as intended for boxed value types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see two possibilities:

- `useaction.Postcondition[goalneeds]` and `current[goalneeds]` return something other than a `bool`. They return an object of a class that has a `ToString()` method which sometimes returns the string `"True"`. The specific objects returned in your case both generate `"True"` but are not the same object, so `==` is false (or the type of those objects overloads the `==` operator in such a way that it returns false, or some other object whose `ToString()` method returns `"False"`).

  (Apparently this turned out to be the case, although the “class” is actually just `object` with a boxed `bool` inside. This does have the described effect because `==` performs reference equality in this case.)
- The indexer of either `useaction.Postcondition` or `current` (or both) has a side-effect that alters its own value. As a result, the second invocation of it returns a *different* result than the first.

Both of these should be immediately visible in the debugger if you just stepped to the line of code you quoted and used the Watch window.

Answer (score 4):

I'd break it down:
*you didn't specify the types... so I dropped in `UnknownType`*

```
UnknownType t1 = useaction.Postcondition[goalneeds];
UnknownType t2 = current[goalneeds];

String s1 = t1.ToString();
String s2 = t2.ToString();

Bool b = (s1 == s2);
```

Then watch each step separately in a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

If the indexers return `object` rather than `bool`, you're getting a reference equality comparison on the boxed values, which will always return false.  In that case, use the `.Equals` method instead.  That will work because it is a virtual method that is overridden by `System.Boolean`.  The `==` operator is overloaded, not overridden.

Alternatively, as Olivier Jacot-Descombes has pointed out, you can unbox both objects; however, this approach will throw an exception if either object is something other than a boxed bool.

Comment: or compare with `(bool)obj1 == (bool)obj2`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks; I edited the answer to incorporate your suggestion.